# Submit when enter is pressed on number input

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I want to make it so when I press enter when clicked on this number input box

```
<input id="answer" type="number" style="display: none;" placeholder="Answer Box"/>
```

it runs this function

```
NextQuestion()
```

I want it so when I press enter it runs the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `.keypress()` and `.click()` function in Jquery to bind multiple events to same function

```
$('#answer').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13)
        //Enter key code is 13, this will capture when enter key pressed
        NextQuestion();
});

$('#answer').click(function(e){
    NextQuestion();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind on keyUp on this input and check if the keyCode is enter (13). In jQuery it will be :

```
$("input#answer").on("keyup",function(e){
    if(e.which==13)
       NextQuestion();
});
```

Comment: Does this need to be in a while True?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: So if I have a jar file with all my functions in it can I just place that code into it?

Comment: I guess you mean a .js file, yes you can add this code in a document ready, if you loaded jquery, it will be :

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("input#answer").on("keyup",function(e){
     if(e.which==13)
        NextQuestion();
   });
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` event listener

```js
var doc = document.getElementById("answer");
doc.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  if(e.which==13) {
    alert('Enter key pressed, move to next question')
    //NextQuestion();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="answer" type="number" style="" placeholder="Answer Box" />
```